# How can I get genie lamp parts besides from the Squeal of Fortune?

Tags: runescape

The [Lamp of the Djinn update](http://services.runescape.com/m=news/squeal-of-fortune-the-lamp-of-the-djinn) says that genie lamp parts can be earned from the Squeal of Fortune, and from skilling and combat drops. However, I have not gotten a single part from skilling or combat. Do I need to do certain skilling activities or kill certain monsters to get the lamp parts? Do some drop lamp parts more often than others?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is pure luck, and it is extremely rare. My stats aren't that great, but while I was slaying, I managed to get a drop. Taking into account that this was after like 10 hours of training in 2 days. It is pretty rare, and None of my mates have gotten anything yet, and they are more "intense" players than me.

Answer (score 0):

When that update was released the most common way to get the lamp parts was slayer. Attacking demons, dragons, or aberrant specters gave the highest chance or these lamp drops.